# Will my mobile be in Doze mode if my battery optimization of mobile is off?

Tags: android

I am facing issues with Alarm manager so for testing purpose i purposely switched off battery optimization of my mobile but it didn't work)
**Now I need answer for 2 things**:

1. Will my mobile go to doze mode if my battery optimization of mobile is off ?
2. How can i give most priority to alarm manager in my code?
   This is battery optimization which is off: [image: This is battery optimization which is off]

Comment: that option you turned off has nothing to do with doze mode. It says *... when you are asleep* means some specific additional manufacturer optimization. Therefore, doze mode will run. To prevent it you have to acquire wakelock.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1786468956):

> Doze reduces battery consumption when the device is not being
>   used for a long time, by temporarily suspending the background tasks
>   performed by CPU and network calls for apps

When will the device go in doze mode?

> Doze mode in an Android device is a state which is satisfied if these
>   three conditions are met:
>
> 1. If the device **screen is off**.
> 2. If the user is **not using the device for a period of time**.
> 3. If the device is in a **non-charging state**.

So battery optimization has nothing with doze mode.

For the second question:

> Standard AlarmManager alarms are **temporarily suspended to the next
>   maintenance window.** The alarms could be overridden in doze mode by
>   writing this statement in the code: `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` or
>   `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`

In maintenance window your applications are not suspended.

To be clear how device run maintenance window and doze mode:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()                                              
this helped me as well but there is flaw in this function actually i want to trigger alarm every 2 hrs and this function only helps when it triggers once in a 24 hrs so this function does not help